# Apply multiple functions to update table using kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to produce/update the output of a table using several functions. Becasue each functions will create separate columns. For me it would be relatively practical to write several functions for it.

To update a table using one function is documented in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/alter-table-update-policy-command

But this case  is not informed. is it even possible to do it ? if so How ?
is is this right way to do this ? `.set-or-append TABLE_NAME<| FUNCTION1 <| FUNCTION2 <| FUNCTION3`

Answer (score 1):

You can chain update policies as much as you need (as long as it does not create a circular reference), this means that Table B can have an update policy that runs a function over Table A and Table C can have an update policy that runs a function over Table B.

If you don't need the intermediate tables you can set their retention policy to 0 days, this means that no data will actually be ingested into these tables.

Comment: could you please give an example ?

Comment: I thought we could do like this 
`.set-or-append TABLE_NAME<| FUNCTION1 <| FUNCTION2 <| FUNCTION3`

Comment: could you please answer it ? @Avnera

Comment: If a function takes the output of another function and so on, you can simply write it using the "pipe" operator, but it is not clear what is the scenario. Can you actually provide an example of the function definitions for this case?